# Getting Node Field Values from Referenced Entity within a Paragraph

Tags: theming, paragraphs, entities

I'm trying to create a featured content paragraph type, however, I can't figure out how to grab anything from the referenced node that is in my entity reference. I don't see any twig documentation that covers this seemingly crucial task at all either.

Does anyone know of a way to call something like get_node() within a twig template?

Comment: Just set the field formatter to Rendered Entity, select a View Mode or create a new one and configure it on the content type you are referencing. Then just add a new twig file and theme it, the field will render the referenced entity using that template.

Comment: This would work but I need to place different fields around the paragraph template depending on other fields within the paragraph type. For instance, I have a field that places an image to one side of the content and the logic within the paragraph template places that image depending on the field.

Comment: This feels like it should be pretty simple, I don't understand why I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in a node template you could access it like so

```
{{ node.field_paragraph.entity.field_in_paragraph.value }}
```

Obviously replace field_paragraph with the machine name of the paragraph field and field_in_paragraph with the machine name of the field inside the paragraph you want.